# BQXX marking code IC part number

Tags: identification, surface-mount, led-driver, markings

I have an IC in hand which its marking is **BQDDVB**.

could you help me find its part number?

Comment: maryam fathalizade - Hi, FYI these are the current "[Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710)". The more information you can supply from that list, the better the chances of identification. You used the tag "led driver" but the question does not currently include any details of the product using that unknown IC. Do you already know that this IC is an LED driver itself? Please [edit] your question to include as much context & known information as possible, as described in those identification guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: maryam fathalizade - Hi again, The answer which has been given seems a likely solution. Do you need more help? If so, please edit your question to explain. If you don't need more help then to mark the topic as solved, please consider ["accepting" the answer which most helped you](/help/someone-answers) (i.e. click the "tick mark" next to that answer, to turn it green). Although accepting an answer isn't mandatory, it is *encouraged* as your question is then shown as having an accepted answer in various lists, it makes it clear that you aren't waiting for more answers & it rewards that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a [SY5882AFAC](http://www.hailihuidz.com/upfile/soft/Datesheet/SY5882.pdf) made by [Silenergy](https://www.silergy.com/) of Hangzhou, China.